# How to converto an application/json response to a JSONObject?

Tags: android, json

Okay, I've received HTTP/1.1 200 OK from an application/json resource.

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://www.my bla bla bla web dot com");
HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
```

This is the response:

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Type:  application/json
Date:          Sat, 23 Nov 2013 21:33:47 GMT

{
    "itemCount":2,
    "items":[{
        "datetime":"2013-11-23 22:23:35",
        "foods":["Spaghetti","Pizza"]
    },{
        "datetime":"2013-11-23 22:23:34",
        "foods":["Pizza","Pasta","Parmigiano Reggiano"]
    }]
}
```

How can I convert this to a JSONObject?

Answer (score 0):

Using this jar `http://www.json.org/java/`

by using this method for parse Stream:

```
    private static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    String line = null;
    try {
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            is.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Then implement a method for parse HTTP wich returns the String you neeed like so:

```
HttpResponse response;
    String result = null;
    try {
        response = client.execute(request);         
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

        if (entity != null) {

            // A Simple JSON Response Read
            InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
            result = convertStreamToString(instream);
            // now you have the string representation of the HTML request
            System.out.println("RESPONSE: " + result);
            instream.close(); 

        }

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    return result;
```

and finally:

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(result);
```

let me now if it's clear!

Comment: Rensponse, is not a JSON. Is a coplete HTTP respone. First 5 lines are not JSON.

Comment: i'll make a better answer...just a second.

Answer (score 0):

```
private class GetTask extends
        AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONItems> {
    @Override
    protected JSONItems doInBackground(String... uri) {
        JSONItems result = new JSONItems();
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpResponse response;
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet(uri[0]);

        String responseString = null;

        try {
            response = httpClient.execute(request);
            StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
            if (statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
                ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                response.getEntity().writeTo(out);
                out.close();
                responseString = out.toString();
                JSONObject jSonObject = new JSONObject(responseString);
                JSONArray jSonArray = jSonObject
                        .getJSONArray("items");
                if (jSonArray.length() > 0) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < jSonArray.length(); j++) {
                        result = convertJSONItems(jSonArray
                                .getJSONObject(j));
                    }
                    return result;
                }
            } else {
                // Closes the connection.
                response.getEntity().getContent().close();
                throw new IOException(statusLine.getReasonPhrase());
            }
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Handle problems..
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Handle problems..
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONItems result) { 
        if (result != null) {
                    //TODO : Do what you want to do .. 
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled(JSONItems result) {

    }

    private JSONItems convertJSONItems(JSONObject obj)
            throws JSONException {
        JSONItems item = new JSONItems();
        item.datetime = obj.getString("datetime");
        item.foods = obj.getString("foods");
        return item;
    }
}
```

Comment: Its possibile JSONItems does not exists?

Comment: You need create JSONItems object 
Create new class as name JSONItems
public class JSONItems {
public String datetime;
public String foods;
} 
It will work